# How to configure squid for inspecting https requests and pages?

Tags: proxy, squid, https, certificate-authority, man-in-the-middle

I wish to allow squid to block https requests by full URL regex matching (not just domain) and to block https responses by inspecting page contents.

Is there some step by step guide for how to set that up?

Particularly, in http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump there is no mention of how exactly to create the certificate, and how would I go about adding the CA to computers in my network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful how you plan on implementing this. Legal and possibly criminal liability could result, depending on where you are.

You need to create the CA certificate yourself. I found a decent guide on the certificate creation here: http://www.freebsdmadeeasy.com/tutorials/freebsd/create-a-ca-with-openssl.php

After you have created the certificate, and loaded it on the proxy server, you'll need to install it on the workstations. I am going to assume you have Windows running in user-world, so installing them can be done through a GPO. Microsoft has info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315%28WS.10%29.aspx